# Resize function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize, document-ready

When the page loads I need #book to take 80% width of the window, and the same need to happen when page is resized. I make the code bellow, but it doesn't work. Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#book').turn();
        $("#book").width = 80 + "%";
    });
    $(document).resize(function(){
        $('#book').css('width', '80%');
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to set the width 2 different ways?

Comment: Try `$( window ).resize(function() {` instead of `$(document).resize(function(){`

Comment: `$("#book").width = 80 + "%";` is incorrect.

Comment: RUJordan sorry, i'm noob in Jquery, j08691 don't work =/ , Rocket Hazmat how is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#book").width = 80 + "%";` isn't correct JS/jQuery.

You can change it to either

```
$('#book').css('width', '80%');
```

or

```
$('#book').width('80%');
```

Also, use `$(window).resize()` instead of `$(document).resize()`

Comment: I get it to work! Nice! So, i just use this $('#magazine').width('80%'); for the width. Now, how can i change the height of # magazine to 50% of the width?

Comment: I don't know if it is right but i use the following code to do what i say above: $('#magazine').height(function(){
   return $('#magazine').width() * 0.5317;
  });

Comment: Your code works, but I would just do something like this for simplicity
    `var magazine = $('#magazine');
    magazine.height(magazine.width() * 0.5317);`